# Coloring text in Mathematica

Tags: cells, text

Mathematica gives the possibility to write normal text as input in cells. One can use bold (ctrl+b) or italic (ctrl+i) for text, but can one color the text? For example writing some red words?

Comment: Well, yes -- the option to color text is in the Format menu. (Voting to close.)

Comment: A better question would be if it is a good idea to color parts of your source code instead of using constructs like `Style[ ]`. But this question seems to be about text cells not input cells...

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Actually, after you mentioned it, it seems to be more about input cells. Also, the question might be about using a shortcut to invoke text coloring...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an image exemplifying my comment:

[image]